# Is the map $f \mapsto \nabla f(x)$ continuous over the space of convex functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, vector-analysis, uniform-continuity, subgradient

Take $V=C(X,\mathbb R)$ as the space of differentiable functions $X \to \mathbb R$ under uniform convergence. Here $X \subset \mathbb R^d$ is some compact domain. For each x is well known the map $\mathcal G:V \to C(X, \mathbb R^d)$ given by $\mathcal G(f) = \nabla f(x)$ is discontinuous. For example consider the sequence $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sin(n x)$. Clearly we have $|f_n(x)| \le 1/n $  and so $f_n \to 0$ uniformly. On the other have  derivatives are $f_n'(x) =  \cos(n x)$ with $f'_n(0)= 1$ and so $f'_n$ does not converge uniformly to $0$.

If we instead restrict $\mathcal G$ to the subset $F \subset X$ of continuous functions then I believe $\mathcal G:F \to C(X, \mathbb R^d)$ is continuous. But I haven't been able to make a clean proof or find a good reference so far.

For a messy proof I can use the heavy machinery in [Corollary 2.3 here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1996-348-04/S0002-9947-96-01581-4/S0002-9947-96-01581-4.pdf) to see that if $f_n \to f$ uniformly then the epigraphs $\{(x,y): x \in X, y \ge f_n(x)\}$ converge to $\{(x,y): x \in X, y \ge f(x)\}$ in the sense of [Kuratowski](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Painlev%C3%A9-Kuratowski_Convergence). Then using other facts I know about set convergence, I can show the gradients converge.

This all seems overblown though. I wonder is this fact well known? Could anyone provide an elementary proof or good reference please?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the notation. Why is $F$ a subset of $X$? Isn't $F$ a functional space and $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: I'm confused too, ${\cal G}$ is not even defined everywhere, so continuity makes no sense. Furthermore, do you mean the map $f \mapsto \nabla f$ or the evaluation $f \mapsto \nabla f(x)$?

Comment: I think it's fairly clear, except it should be $F\subseteq V$, the set of convex functions, and $V$ should be at least $C^1$ not $C$.